# Facebook PHP SDK returning undefined

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to print out the name of my own personal profile on a span. I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK V5.x and I'm using my app's id and secret and an access token for my page that I manage that I gave permissions for.

Here is the print out code:

```
<?php echo $user['name']; ?>
```

Here is the code I am using to try to extract the user name:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.12',
  'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
 ]);

try {

$response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', '{access-token}');
$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

It just says "undefined" though. Why? I'm not getting any kind of fatal error.

Comment: "an access token for my page that I manage"....why not a user token, if you want to get the name of your "personal profile"? and did you debug the token? did you debug the response?

Comment: Well originally I was trying to retrieve the number of users attending an event. I want to use the events of a certain page. No I didn't debug the response. Graph API explorer shows everything as fine when I try it. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: well, debug the response then...still not sure if you want to get the name of a page or the name of a user though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

after setting the fb id,secret ect

```
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo "Response Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
} catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "SDK Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

$oAuth2Client = $FB->getOAuth2Client();
    if (!$accessToken->isLongLived())
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);

    $response = $FB->get("/me?fields=id, first_name, last_name, email,)", $accessToken);
    $userData = $response->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    $userData = $response->getDecodedBody();
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($userData);
```